# Spring security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter reading application.properties

Tags: spring-security

In my application, I want to configure spring security for configuring HSTS support.
I have modified pom.xml for adding required libraries.

Now I want to read the HSTS related configurations from application.properties. I have added the code as below;

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Value("${app.security.headers.hsts}")
    private boolean hsts;
    
    @Value("${app.security.headers.hsts.includeSubDomains}")
    private boolean includeSubDomains;
    
    @Value("${app.security.headers.hsts.maxAge}")
    private long maxAge;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        if(hsts) {
            http.headers().
            httpStrictTransportSecurity().
            includeSubDomains(includeSubDomains).
            maxAgeInSeconds(maxAge);
        }
    }
}
```

However the spring application is failed to start. It is throwing below error,

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.security.headers.hsts' in value "${app.security.headers.hsts}"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
```

Comment: Can you also share your application.properties file?

Comment: It was mistake from my side; the application.properties is not kept on the spring config location; after adding the --spring.config.location parameter as command line argument; it started reading the properties.
Thank you for reply Onur !!!